# You have an error in your SQL syntax; WHERE username='115110030'' at line 1

Tags: php, mysql

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE username='115110030'' at line 1

I tried so hard but cant solve the problem, please help me solve this

---

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $username       = $_SESSION['username'];
    $name           = $_POST['nama'];   
    $tempat_lahir   = $_POST['tempat_lahir'];   
    $tgl_lahir      = $_POST['tgl_lahir'];
    $gender         = $_POST['gender'];
    $alamat         = $_POST['alamat'];
    $telp           = $_POST['telp'];
    $email          = $_POST['email'];
    $image_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $path  = "assets/img/photo/" . $image_name;
    $upload = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $path);

    if (empty($image_name))
    {
        $update = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET name='$name', tempat_lahir='$tempat_lahir', tanggal_lahir='$tgl_lahir', gender='$gender', alamat='$alamat', telp='$telp', email='$email', WHERE username='$username'") or die(mysql_error());
        echo "<script>alert('Data Berhasil Di Update.'); window.location.assign('index.php');</script>";
    }
    else if(!empty($image_name))
    {
        $update = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET name='$name', tempat_lahir='$tempat_lahir', tanggal_lahir='$tgl_lahir', gender='$gender', alamat='$alamat', telp='$telp', email='$email', image='$image_name' WHERE username='$username'") or die(mysql_error());
        echo "<script>alert('Data Berhasil Di Update.'); window.location.assign('index.php');</script>";
    }

}
?>
```

---

Comment: You have an odd comma right before `WHERE` keyword. Remove it.

Comment: Show us how you "tried so hard". There are SIMPLE debugging strategies for this.  For instance, do you even know which SQL statement the error is coming from?  It looks like you haven't tried at all.

Comment: **WARNING:** You're open to SQL injection. Also the `mysql_*` library has been dropped. Consider using [`mysqli`](http://php.net/mysqli) or [`pdo`](http://php.net/pdo).

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
$update = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET name='$name', tempat_lahir='$tempat_lahir', tanggal_lahir='$tgl_lahir', gender='$gender', alamat='$alamat', telp='$telp', email='$email', WHERE username='$username'") or die(mysql_error());
```

with this:

```
$update = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET name='$name', tempat_lahir='$tempat_lahir', tanggal_lahir='$tgl_lahir', gender='$gender', alamat='$alamat', telp='$telp', email='$email' WHERE username='$username'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Also, you should resolve your SQL Injections issues: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php